# UIImagePickerController camera live preview wrong orientation in landscape iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, screen-orientation

I have an iPad app that implements UIImagePickerController source type camera. When the rotation is enabled for the device, and if I select camera from image picker while kept in portrait mode(app supports only landscape mode), the camera view is displayed 90 degrees rotated. If we lock the rotation, camera is working fine. Code for presenting camera view is  -

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil
     ];
```

Any one has any suggestions?